# VirtualBox detects only less than half of the cores and designates ANY number of cores to be used by 'red' on a machine with a high number of cores

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, virtualization, cloud-computing

I have been using **Oracle VM VirtualBox** for many years and even on systems with only two cores, I have always seen the 'green' light for 50% of the cores.

To my surprise, currently on a Linux machine with **80 cores**, I **only see 32 cores** in VirtaulBox! But that is not all: Oracle VM also gives me a red flag for even very low number of cores: e.g. even 2 (out of 32) is considered 'bad'!

[image: Here is the image showing 32 cores and all in red -- I do not have enough reputation to post images, please fix this part.]

Information about the cloud machine I am using:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64)
RAM: 218 GB
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                80
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-79
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             80
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 94
Model name:            Intel Core Processor (Skylake, IBRS)
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               2194.916
BogoMIPS:              4389.83
Virtualization:        VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-79
```

What is happening and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: What kind of machine is that? 80 sockets? There is no motherboard on earth that has 80 sockets, as far as I know, and that might be the cause of the issue..

Comment: I think your issue is a combination of trying to do nested virtualization (VirtualBox already in a KVM virtual machine) and the fact that [VirtualBox only supports up to 32 virtual CPU processors per guest](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-processor).

Comment: @Magnus This is a cloud machine built on OpenNebula. Same as if one had access to Piz Daint (https://www.top500.org/system/177824) and they were allocated a machine with 80 processors from it.

Comment: I agree with @Deltik, nested virtualization and too many CPU:s is likely the culprit here.